# how to get number of updates since particular timestamp for facebook and twitter developer apis

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

how to get number of updates since particular timestamp for

facebook and 
twitter developer apis

I want to get number of updates since a given timestamp to be shown in our application. Want to know whether Twitter and Facebook already provides that or we need to do it on our side?

Example i show latest newsfeed at timestamp T1 . After 10 minutes i again want to ask facebook apis to get me number of updates since timestamp T1 for that user in Newsfeed ( or in other words , the number of new newsfeed) Does that kind of API exist in facebook or twiter

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provides a JSON feed showing the status of the most recent push:
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/api_status.php

Example output

```
{
   "push": {
      "status": "Complete",
      "updated": "2012-03-28T23:12:13-07:00",
      "id": 7022365
   },
   "current": {
      "health": 1,
      "subject": "Facebook Platform is Healthy"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thats not what i am looking for . I need to make a call to facebook, passing a timestamp say of 1 hour ago and pass a oauth token . The facebook should return number of updates since that timestamp. Do we have such apis? Do we have similar APIs for twitter?

Comment: No, that's the only place to see where the API has been updated programmatically - most updates are announced on the Blog. If I'm misunderstanding you and you're talking about checking if a user's feed or other data from the API has been updated, the documentation covers this in detail - FQL, Graph API and Realtime API all provide this

Comment: I am not looking for API updates. I am looking for Data updates for a given user like NewsFeed updates since a given timestamp.
I have Edited the original question too , probably i had put wrongly initially